# changing the iTunes Artwork after submission

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My app has been approved by the app store and is currently visible.
However I want to change the itunes Artwork.
How can I do that ?

Comment: The artwork is bundled with the iOS project. So you'll need to package your app again and submit a new version. Might be a good time to add social sharing or a bug fix, since you'll still need to wait on the review queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change it with an update - the artwork should appear once you've submitted an update with the new artwork.